# Getting the input strings into an array and sort the array of strings alphabetically

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want to input some strings and sort them alphabetically, at most 100 strings and the length of each string is less than 50, but I get a Segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
}

int main()
{
    char sequences[100][50];
    int nr_of_strings;
    scanf("%d", &nr_of_strings);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < nr_of_strings; ++i)
        scanf("%s", sequences[i]);
    qsort(sequences, nr_of_strings, sizeof(char *), comp);
    for(i = 0; i < nr_of_strings; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", sequences[i]);
}
```

Comment: In your `comp` function, before you call `strcmp`, try to print the arguments, to see if they really are what you think they are. Or use a debugger.

Comment: Don't think you can do that with 2-D array. Think about creating array of `char *` for each string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
...
qsort(sequences, nr_of_strings, sizeof(char *), comp);
```

to

```
return strcmp ((const char *) a, (const char *) b);
...
qsort(sequences, nr_of_strings, sizeof(char [50]), comp);
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have tried this, still Segmentation fault.

Comment: @jfly `still Segmentation fault.` Surely? It's work fine to me.

Comment: Sorry, I only change 'qsort(sequences, nr_of_strings, sizeof(char *), comp);' to 'qsort(sequences, nr_of_strings, sizeof(char [50]), comp);'. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the 2d array like this. It worked for me.

```
char** sequences;
int i;
sequences = (char**)malloc(100 * sizeof(char*));

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sequences[i] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
}
```